# how to record PCM for hours , but save only last 5min of recording when stopped?

Tags: java, android, audio, audio-recording

I want to record PCM audio for hours , but I want to save only the last 5 min of recording when the button STOP is pressed. Meaning when START is pushed and the recording has reached 5min , the next step would be to delete the beginning of recording and to append additional read buffer to the recording so the 5 min always remains the same. I need to do this using AudioRecord.

I've tried using AudioRecord class to do 20s recording instead of 5min. I've read bytes into one big byte[] buffer. When START is pressed bytes are read to byte[] buffer and when 20s are reached it begins to overwrite the byte[] buffer from beginning , when 40s are reached it again begins to overwrite byte[] buffer from beginning, when STOP is pushed I rearrange the byte[] buffer into correct sequence and write to file. This method works, but using it I need to allocate memory for byte[] buffer from the start , and 5 min is too big , I hit heap size limit and run out of memory. I'm doing this using sampling rate of 44100Hz.

So, is there a better method to make 5min recording as described above without allocating too much memory ?

Comment: My guess is that any method you use will need at least that amount of memory.

Comment: You can avoid the java heap size limit with a native allocation in jni code and a circular buffer implemented there, however, you are still running on a device with limited memory and an OOM killer that will enthusiastically dispatch background processes when it runs out of memory for foreground ones.  A lower sampling rate or mono would reduce memory needs, as of course would the already mentioned compression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have enough memory, you have two choices.

First choice is to use the disk as buffer, if you have any, this is simple, but if your disk is flash based you'll be wearing it down for no reason.

Second choice is to compress. If you don't need PCM you can encode it as MP3. If you need PCM, there might be other choices. Sound is very redundant and should be quite compressible, even losslessly. But sooner or later you'll reach a limit of your RAM.

Answer (score 0):

Write it to a file instead of keeping it in memory?

Comment: keep in mind that I have to record for multiple hours. When pressed STOP save only the last 5min. PCM file takes a lot of space , recording it for hours is not a good idea

Comment: I think the suggestion is to do the same circular buffering with a temporary file that you are trying to do in memory.  However, it may be worth thinking if this adds up to significant consumption of the flash write lifetime.

Comment: What you said about the AudioRecord class going back to the beginning and overwriting...  That is sometimes called a "circular buffer."  Buddy probaby meant for you to implement a circular buffer in a file.  That is, after five minutes, seek back to the start of the file and keep over-writing it.

Comment: the problem is when I start overwriting a file , all data in the file is lost , only the new overwriten information remains. Unless there is a way to keep the old data , I mean overwrite file as if a simple byte[] buffer. Is there such a way ?

Comment: That's due to the particular java APIs you are using to access the file, not to the idea of using a file, so it is something that can be solved properly.  (While I like it even less than the idea of using a file to begin with, a very crude "for today" workaround would be to use an array of 20-second files.)

Comment: Probably only two files 5min long would be enough. Always overwriting them by turn , when stopped you could reconstruct actual 5 min recording. Say I do this continuous recording for a few days , what is the impact to flash write lifetime ?

Comment: Only ever for a few days on a given device?  Probably not much.  Also, unless the storage is fairly full, a decent storage implementation (at the underlying level invisible to you) would move moving the files across the memory device, not storing them back in the same location, so the wear would be spread out.  But if you had this running permanently, and especially if it were confined to a small number of physical flash blocks, it could eventually become an issue.